# Create a table of solutions at specific parameter values for Nsolve

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I want to create a table or list of solutions for some parameter values
to see it rather than manually checking for each value

```
eq[α_, k_, x_] := Sin[k + α] + k Sin[k] == x*Cos[k]
sol[x_?NumericQ, k_ /; 0 <= k <= Pi] := α /. NSolve[{eq[α, k, x], 0 <= α <= Pi}, α, Reals]
```

I tried with

```
Table[sol[x, k], {x, 0.1, 3, 0.1}, {k, 0.1, 3, 0.1}]
```

which gives me an output in a "grey box" which is not complete and I think it only shows a few solutions, while I would like to see all solutions with a gap of `0.1` from `{x, 0.1, 3}` and `{k, 0.1, 3}`. Can I see the full output explicitly somehow? Or is there an alternate to `Table` for this purpose which is more convenient?

Comment: Your syntax for the iterators is wrong. It should be `Table[sol[x, k], {x, 0.1, 3, 0.1}, {k, 0.1, 3, 0.1}]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks. I corrected it. It still gives me output in a grey box, with `....28...` how do I get rid of this box and see the full solution list explicitly? like to which `x` and `k` value a particular solution corresponds to etc?

Comment: If it is the same gray box as one sees in the output of something like `RandomReal[1, 10^5]`, then just click on the `show all` button. If it is a different kind of gray box, maybe you could include an image of it (for instance, by using the menu item`Edit | Copy As | Bitmap`).

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes thanks. I can see the solutions by clicking `show all` button. It however does not show to which `x` and `k` value a particular solution corresponds to. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps to visualize the results:

```
eq[α_, k_, x_] := Sin[k + α] + k Sin[k] == x*Cos[k];
sol[x_?NumericQ, 
   k_ /; 0 <= k <= Pi] := α /. 
    NSolve[{eq[α, k, x], 0 <= α <= Pi}, α, 
     Reals] /. α -> {};
a = Table[sol[x, k], {x, 0.1, 3, 0.1}, {k, 0.1, 3, 0.1}];
MatrixForm[
 ArrayFlatten[{{{{"x\\k"}}, {Range[0.1, 3, 0.1]}}, {Partition[
     Range[0.1, 3, 0.1], 1], a}}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect.